# XSLT with XPAth 2.0 and Java expressions

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

I would like to use XPath 2.0, more specifically the `distinct-values` function. I downloaded the Saxon Home Edition because it can do XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 but now it moans about not being able to invoke java stuff.

`Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java}java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new(). Note that direct calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE;`

The built in processor in JRE has no problem with java expressions. Is there some way to mix Saxon-HE and the default JRE processor? Or is there some free processor that can do both?

Side question: Why is XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 implemented so seldom? It's a few years old but all the big wig processors can't do it... :-(

Comment: On your side question: Developing an XSLT 2.0 processor might not be too profitable, especially when many people are asking for "some free processor".

Comment: Saxon 9.1.0.8 is no longer available for download from the saxon sourceforge site. It is still available on the maven repo. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.saxon/saxon/9.1.0.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Saxon 9 and [extension functions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions.xml) you need to use one of the commercial editions or you need to use the [new mechanism of integrated extension functions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions.xml) or you need to use Saxon 9.1 (still available).
As for formatting dates, XSLT and XPath 2.0 have support for the schema data types xs:date and xs:dateTime and there are functions to format these, like http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date.
As for support for XSLT and XPath 2.0, XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery 1.0, you should be able to find implementations for that beside Saxon. XSLT 2.0 is a complex specification and there are other implementations from IBM and Intel for instance, but not as open source projects.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the second question (Why is XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 implemented so seldom?) is implicit in your first - it's because of the economics of the software market - so many people would like to have everything for free, and that makes it hard to create a business case for developing the software.

If you can't afford the £50 for a Saxon Professional Edition license, you have the option to use "integrated extension functions" as Martin suggests, or to stick with Saxon-B 9.1 as Dimitre suggests.